# Do All Subsets of $\Bbb N$ Have Predicates?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question:

Is it true that for any subset $S$ of $\mathbb N$, there is a predicate $φ(x)$ in this language $S$ such that $S$ = $\{n\in \mathbb N | φ(n)\}$?

Here's my thought process so far. If everything that's $\in$ $\mathbb N$ has some predicate, the number of predicates of the language (POL) must be equal to the number of sets of $\mathbb N$.

So, |POL| = | $P(\mathbb N) |$.

Now, POL $\subseteq$ WFF

But the |WFFs| = |$\mathbb N$|

And |$\mathbb N$| $\ne$ $P(\mathbb N) |$.

Does it thereby follow that |POL| $\ne$ |$P (\mathbb N)|$?

Any advice, tips, tricks or suggestions about how to answer this question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is WFF?$ $

Comment: @Kenny: Well-formed formula.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your proof.

Answer (score 4):

The proof is correct. Assuming that you mean the language of arithmetic, or any other countable language.

Consider, on the other hand, the uncountable language where for every $S\subseteq\Bbb N$ we have a predicate symbol $R_S$ which is interpreted as $S$ itself in $\Bbb N$. There, indeed, every subset of the natural numbers is definable by a predicate. But since the language is uncountable, this is not a problem.

Comment: I do mean the language of arithmetic. So that's good. But I'm not sure I understand why if the language at hand is uncountable then the predicates of that language, a subset of the language, is = $\mathbb N$

Comment: Mathematics is freedom. I am free to define a language, and I am free to add uncountably many predicate symbols. And I am free to choose an interpretation which is the natural numbers, where each predicate is interpreted as its indexing set.